# Link between the largest eigenvalue and the largest entry of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a symmetric (or Hermitian) matrix with size $n\times n$.

If it helps, one can consider $A$ tridiagonal (and symmetric).

By spectral theorem, there exists $\lambda_1\geq ... \geq \lambda_n$ real eigenvalues.

Are there known connection (such as inequalities etc) between its largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and its largest entry $\max_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|$ ?

Comment: $\lambda_1 \le n \max\limits_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$. The coefficient $n$ is optimal,
it can be achieved by matrix with all entries $1$.
In fact, as a corollary of [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), we have a stronger result $\lambda_1 \le \max\limits_i \left(a_{ii} +\sum\limits_{j\ne i} |a_{ij}|\right)$

Comment: @achillehui thanks ! and do you know any lower bound result ?

Comment: An answer to myself, if $A$ is $n\times n$ symmetric, then, the maximum eigenvalue is bounded above by $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}$.

Comment: This last comment cannot be correct, right. Consider a diagonal matrix with, say positive eigenvalues. Surely the maximum eigenvalue must be bigger than the average?

Comment: The above comment by @anonymus is violently false: Take the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $\lambda_{\max} = 1$, $n=2$ and the comment would imply $1 \leq \frac{1}{2}$.